# Correct usage of self in python instance

Tags: python, self

I have a class that I defined in the following way:

```
class Time:
    def print_time(self, am_pm):
        if am_pm == 'AM':
            tot_seconds = self.hour * 3600 + self.minute * 60 + self.second
        else: 
...         tot_seconds = self.hour * 3600 + self.minute * 60 + self.second + 12*3600.0
        print('%.2d:%.2d:%.2d' % (self.hour, self.minute, self.second))
        print('Seconds passed since midnight: ', tot_seconds)
```

I create an instance of Time with `start = Time` and then I specify the instance attributes as `start.hour = 10`, `start.minute = 5`, `start.second = 2`.

When I call the method `print_time`, if I do `Time.print_time(start, 'AM')` then I get the correct output. But if I try to pass `start` as `self` it does not work:

```
start.print_time('AM')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-68-082a987f3007>", line 1, in <module>
    start.print_time('PM')

TypeError: print_time() missing 1 required positional argument: 'am_pm'
```

But why it is so? I thought that `start` would be the subject of the method invocation and so it would count as the first parameter and so I would need to specify only the `am_pm` parameter in `print_time()`. Why is this wrong?

Comment: You have to change `start = Time` to `start = Time()`. `Time.print_time(start, 'AM')` works coincidentally, `start` is not actually an instance of `Time` here.

Answer (score 3):

`start = Time` does not actually construct an instance of your class. Rather, you assign the class definition `Time` to the variable `start`. You need open/close parentheses after a class name in order to construct an instance.

In other words, `start.print_time()` in your case is attempting to treat `print_time` like a static function -- as if you were simply calling `Time.print_time()` without an instance.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Oh gosh what a silly mistake. I was banging my head for nothing, thanks a lot for your quick reply! :)

Comment: Haha! No prob, I've done it myself more times than I care to admit.

Answer (score 0):

class Time:

```
def __init__(self, am_pm, ):

    self.am_pm=am_pm

    self.hour=10

    self.minute=5

    self.second=2

def print_time(self):

    if self.am_pm=="AM":

        tot_seconds=self.hour * 3600 + self.minute * 60 + self.second

        print(tot_seconds)

    else:

        tot_seconds = self.hour * 3600 + self.minute * 60 + self.second + 12*3600.0

        print('%.2d:%.2d:%.2d' %(self.hour, self.minute, self.second))

        print( 'Seconds passed since midnight: ',tot_seconds)
```

start=Time("AM")

start.print_time()

except you change the object of the class ( start ) as self. ie

```
      self=Time("AM")
      self.print_time()
```

You can specify any object but not keywords